# Select data from two table, where child table's two column have same foreign key

Tags: sql-server

**Table1**

```
StaffId int primary key,
StaffName nvarchar(150)
```

**Table2**

```
DoctorIdRef int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Table1(StaffId),
AdminIdRef  int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Table1(StaffId),
```

This is my two tables structure and I want to select data like

```
select DoctorIdRef, DoctorName, AdminIdRef, AdminName
```

Comment: Hint : `INNER JOIN` to `Table1` twice and use different table alias

Answer (score 1):

```
select DoctorIdRef, Doctor.StaffName DoctorName, AdminIdRef, Adminr.StaffName AdminName
from Table2 
left join Table1 as Doctor on Doctor.StaffId = Table2.DoctorIdRef 
left join Table1 as Adminr on Adminr.StaffId = Table2.AdminIdRef
```